# Filling textfields on webserver with python?

Tags: python, linux, web

iam relativ new to Python and a noob in programming.
I wonder if there is a way to fill textfields
on a website?
Iam thinking about writing an python application for linux terminals where the **user input will be send to the website, placed in the right webforms and then prints the formatted output back in the linux terminal**. Is this possible?

It would be nice if such a thing is possible in python since I am just learning it and I like it so far.

I also tried looking for related stuff but I don't know where to start. Found this page here which seems like the right direction but I am not sure:
https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html
Also this seems right (https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but I am not sure if I can get the new page contents back on the terminal.

Comment: take a look at [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried it out but i struggle with connection to a server. I also find the documentation a bit hard to understand.  but it seems like the right direction and a good start for this project. thanks again